# FPS weapon with gluLookAt

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, glut, glulookat

I'm developing a 3D maze-like game, just for learning(and of course for fun :) ). I have made the maze, I can move between the walls in First-Person mode. My only problem is, that I want some kind of weapon for my First-Person view( like an FPS game). To moving in the maze I'm using `gluLookAt`. 
Code snippets:

```
void RenderScene(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();    
    gluLookAt(x, 1.0f, z,x + lx, 1.0f, z + lz,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

....

```
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]); //texture binding
            glScalef(7.0f, 8.0f, 7.0f);
            glTranslatef(-(r * 2), 0.0f, -(c * 2)); //place the maze walls(cubes)
            glCallList(mazeListId);//using the display list


}
    void SpecialKeys(int key, int xx, int yy)
{
    // ...
    int state;
    float fraction = 1.0f;


    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        angle -= 0.15f;
        lx = sin(angle);
        lz = -cos(angle);
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        angle += 0.15f;
        lx = sin(angle);
        lz = -cos(angle);
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        x += lx * fraction;
        z += lz * fraction;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        x -= lx * fraction;
        z -= lz * fraction;
        break;
    }
```

I've tried to do this with my cube( the cube is now the "weapon").

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);
    glTranslatef(x + lx, -0.5f, z + lz);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    drawCube(2);
    glPopMatrix();
```

With this the cube moves forward és backward perfectly, but when I turn left or right, it stays at its position.
Can somebody help me with the turning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem! I didn't made the right order with the transformations. I share my code, if someone will need it in the future.

```
gluLookAt(x, 1.0f, z,
        x + lx, 1.0f, z + lz,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x + lx, -0.5f, z + lz);
    glRotatef(-angle* 57.2957795, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f); // offset
    drawCube(2);
glPopMatrix();
```